# A gift loophole to avoid taxes in US

Tags: united-states, tax-law, gift

Let's say for the sake of concreteness a US person owns a property in a foreign country. If the person decides to sell the property, then he/she owes capital gain taxes. Now here is a gift scheme to seemingly avoid that. That person gifts the property to a foreign person that has no relationship with US. The only obligation here is that the property owner needs to report the gift, and this will be counted as his/her life-time gift tax exemption limit (about 13 million dollars). Assuming the value does not exceed the limit there is no tax obligations here. Then the receiver of the gift sells the property and gifts back the money to the original owner. Again, here does not seem to be any tax obligations, only that the receiver should report the amount if it exceeds 100k.

Is this a valid loophole or are there laws preventing from this happening?

Comment: Assuming that the property is worth $8,000,000 then $18,000 of the gift is exempt from the gift tax, which falls on the donor. It does not matter whether the recipient is a US person or not, what matters is whether the donor is. Did you have in mind dividing the interest in the property among a few hundred individuals so that you could multiply the exemption to cover the value of the property?

Comment: @user6726 Thanks, I was not aware of the 8 mil law. In that case I guess you will need a massive team!

Comment: if your plan includes the word "scheme" it's a good bet it isn't legal.

Comment: @TigerGuy meh, maybe in US English but many legal mechanisms over here are literally called “schemes”.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is this a valid loophole or are there laws preventing from this
> happening?

This is not a valid loophole. This counts as tax fraud.

If a gift is made with an expectation that the person making the gift will receive something in return, it is improper and illegal to report this as a gift rather than a sale of the property.

Comment: Thanks, how do they determine that, when there are no concrete laws to determine the intention? (I know now that becomes illegal and not a loophole, but this is almost impossible to catch or prove the intentions.)

Comment: Here is also another way to obfuscate even more (almost impossible to catch): the first owner gifts to a non-US person A then A gifts to person B (again non-US) then B gifts backs to the original owner.

Comment: @user127776 It is easier to prove intentions than you'd think and this can be done with circumstantial evidence. Disgruntled ex-spouses, mistresses, employees, and relatives are all informants sometimes, and there are other tricks to catching these deals too. Journalists also figure out what politicians and celebrities are up to, leading to investigations. This said, vast amounts of all sorts of tax frauds never get caught. Cheating on your taxes is a lot safer than car jacking or robbing a bank.

Comment: @user127776 - the site is not intended to help people break the law in a way that minimizes getting caught.

Comment: @ohwilleke Posting about on a  Q&A site about "hypotheticals" that are similar to your actions is also pretty significant evidence of intent.